# Custom View like textview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to make custom Emoji app with custom emoticons.For that i added UILabel & UIImageView on UIScrollview.But the cursor will create problem.

I created a custom view which accept images and text,but when i move cursor to some place the text string disturb.Please help me out with some custom codes or example.
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also disturbed because I'm not getting you! Please do add some code or screenshots that you want to make/tried?

Comment: could you provide more detail on how you planned to handle both text and image in a single view?

Comment: uivew or uitextview ,what do you use .both text and image, give some more information

Comment: I am trying to make custom Emoji app with custom emoticons.For that i added uilabels & uiimageView  on UIscrollview.But the cursor will create problem.

Comment: What do you mean "the cursor will create problem"? We aren't going to write your code for you. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support.I will create my own custom textview with UILabel & UIImageView.
Thanks once again.